# Is there a difference between 'They all had done something' and 'They had all done something'?

Tags: grammaticality, learning

So, I preparing for this test and one of the questions is this.
[image: test screen shot]

```
The teacher remarked that they all had done it very badly.
```

Why is this sentence structure wrong?

I found [this question in English learner stackexchange](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/29551/meaning-and-the-position-of-all-in-a-sentence) that expands more on the position of the word *all* in a sentence.

Comment: Answered at [' ... all had taken' or ' ... had all taken'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/314008/all-had-taken-or-had-all-taken/563444#563444). ' ... had all ...' is/can be the unmarked (normal) ordering, but ' ... all had ...' is perfectly acceptable, putting stress on _all_ rather than the whole sentence.

Comment: No:  but "all" is an adjunct as is evident from the fact that when the verb is an auxiliary, as it is in your example, it _preferentially_ follows rather than precedes it.

Comment: The important point is that where the verb is an auxiliary, quantificational adjuncts like "all", "both" and "each" follow rather than precede it. Which explains why "They had all done something" is _preferable_ to "They all had done something".

Comment: @BillJ This is no adjunct according to CoGEL but a pronoun.

Comment: @LPH. Adjunct is a function and pronoun is a part of speech. You can't compare them. This "all" is a determinative in a 'fused-head NP. And of course it's an adjunct. It can't be a complement so what else could it be? Get an up-to-date grammar!

Comment: @BillJ Can a pronoun be an adjunct?

Comment: @LPH What is the relevance of your question?

Comment: @BillJ Obviously, if a pronoun can't be an adjunct and if "all" is a pronoun, then it can't be an adjunct.

Comment: But "all" is **not** a pronoun. It's a determinative in a fused-head NP functioning as an adjunct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> (CoGEL **5.16** p. 258) […] *All* and *both* can occur after the head, either immediately or in the *M* adverb position (after the operator, *cf* 8.16). For *all* and *both* we have, then, the following possibilities:
> […]
> *They* were *all* accepted.
> ?*They all* were accepted.

The symbol "?" in CoGEL means that native speakers are unsure about the acceptability. This means then that "They had all done something" poses no problem of acceptability, whoever reads or hears it, but "They all had done something"  might sound strange to some native speakers. This is reflected in this [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=They+all+had+done%2CThey+had+all+done&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2CThey%20all%20had%20done%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CThey%20had%20all%20done%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2CThey%20all%20had%20done%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CThey%20had%20all%20done%3B%2Cc0) (duplicated below).

[image]

---

*Clarification on the meaning of "operator"*

> (CoGEL **2.49** p. 80) The definition of operator as first auxiliary raises the question of what happens if the corresponding positive declarative has no auxiliary, and therefore no operator. In such cases, the verb "DO" is introduced  as a "dummy" auxiliary to perform the function of operator.

More specifically, the operator is that auxiliary that is selected as a reference for the placement of the negative particle and the changes in the positions of the subject when forming negations, questions and negative questions.

- The ship *may* have been sunk. — The ship *may* **not** have been sunk. — *May*  **the ship** have been sunk?
- They came yesterday. — They *did* **not** come yesterday. — *Did* **they** come yesterday? — *Did* **not** **they** come yesterday?

Comment: This answer just repeats my last comment, except that it doesn't mention the useful bit about auxiliary verbs. The term 'auxiliary' is much better and more common than 'operator'.

Comment: @BillJ I would have read your comment a little later as I was in a hurry I went on with my answer without reading them first. There is in my answer, however, the "often" required advantage of some references.

Comment: @BillJ I don't think so; the term "operator" in CoGEL has a particular meaning that goes beyond that of "auxiliary". I'm sorry the exact definition escapes me now and that I can't make you aware of it, but for the time being I'll keep to the term "operator".

Comment: Why? Virtually no one uses the tern 'operator'. It causes unnecessary confusion.The term 'auxiliary is what everyone uses. It goes to show how out-of-date CoGEL is!

Comment: @BillJ I'm afraid that you criticize CoGEL without knowing it sufficiently. "Operator" is not a word used lightly in CoGEL, but I have to brush up on that (I told you). In CoGEL, both "auxiliary" and "operator" are use, and not in a synonymous way; the difference matters.

Comment: I know all about CoGEL, especially that is well out-of-date. I don't care how "lightly" it uses the term 'operator'; it simply won't do in 2021.

Comment: @BillJ The CoGEL is a grammar with a revised edition (2010) currently on sale, and after all the CGEL dates from 2002. What is new,  is not necessarily more exact. As there are people that believe in the grammar such as CoGEL explains it, I believe that I can also be one of those believers, as long as my sense of language agrees with theirs.  Anyway, I disagree strongly with some of what appears in CGEL.

Comment: Most grammarians agree that GGEL is superior to CoGEL. Have you actually got a copy of CGEL? Give an example of something you disagree with.

Comment: @BillJ A simple one is that question we discussed some time ago concerning wh-words that imply a question according to CGEL; I don't agree with that at all; neither do I agree with their reclassification of nouns, as explained in Pullum's "*The final proof*"  (Lexical categorization in English dictionaries and traditional grammars). Sorry, I can't go on: I have been suspended on another site, with the consequence of not being allowed to use chat sections whatever the site I am in; as my comment here is already one too many I must stop.

Comment: I don't know much about the nuances of English grammar protocols, but this one answers my question, so I'm accepting it.